# Preloaded database corruption issue in Android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I have an android application that begins by downloading a large database to the sdcard (a little over 50mb) in an asynctask.  The download code is as follows.

```
HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if(filePath.exists() && filePath.length() > 10000.00)
{
    downloaded = (int) filePath.length();
    conexion.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (filePath.length()) + "-");
}
else
    conexion.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");

conexion.setDoInput(true);
conexion.setDoOutput(true);
conexion.setUseCaches(false);
conexion.connect();
```

...

```
try {
    totalFileLength = lengthOfFile + downloaded;
    progressDialog.setMax(lengthOfFile + downloaded);
    // downlod the file
    input = new BufferedInputStream(conexion.getInputStream());
    output = (downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(filePath): new FileOutputStream(filePath,true);
    bout = new BufferedOutputStream(output, 1024);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    while ((count = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0 && running) {
        downloaded += count;
        // publishing the progress....
        //onProgressUpdate((int)(downloaded*100/lengthOfFile));
        progressDialog.setProgress(downloaded);
        bout.write(data, 0, count);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
} finally {
    try {
        input.close();
        bout.flush();
        bout.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

After downloading the file completely I open the database and add a table to it.

```
try {
    myDbHelper.myDataBase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FAVORITES (_id integer primary key autoincrement, MushroomID INTEGER)");
    success = true;
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    throw sqle;
}
```

Now, this code works wonderfully on every device I run it on, but several of my users are getting this error on the execSQL line.  It seems like it is not working on the Samsung Galaxy SII alone (there hasn't been a complaint and subsequent stacktrace with this error with any other phone) but I'm not entirely sure its just this phone.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.daleroy.fungifieldguide/net.daleroy.fungifieldguide.activities.FungiFieldGuide}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FAVORITES (_id integer primary key autoincrement, MushroomID INTEGER)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FAVORITES (_id integer primary key autoincrement, MushroomID INTEGER)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1904)
       at net.daleroy.fungifieldguide.services.MushroomService.MakeFavoriteTable(MushroomService.java:118)
       at net.daleroy.fungifieldguide.services.MushroomService.OpenDB(MushroomService.java:64)
       at net.daleroy.fungifieldguide.activities.FungiFieldGuide.onCreate(FungiFieldGuide.java:73)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

I've received a copy of the database downloaded from a user with a sgs2 and the checksum of the file is off.  I also cannot see any data or data structure in the file when I open with sqlite manager (firefox plugin).  I let him download a copy of the database directly and place it in his data folder and the application works fine.  So the problem is somewhere in the download process.

Comment: Which version of sqllite db are you using?  E.g. Do you use [WAL](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html)?

Comment: I loaded it up into sqlite manager (a firefox plugin).  It says schema version is 80.  The file type is .s3db and when I download it to my application I rename it to type .db.  It says user version is 0, so I'm not sure.

Comment: did you compare byte per byte the two files? is the size correct?

Comment: is it possible that you start the download twice at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the API level 9 (Android 2.3) you can use [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to handle long-running HTTP downloads:

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running
>   HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
>   particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the
>   download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and
>   retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and
>   system reboots.

Here is the example project which demonstrates DownloadManager usage: [Android DownloadManager Example](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/).

I think you can even try to backport DownloadManager to the previous Android versions (if you need to support them). Its source code can be found here: [DownloadManager.java](http://google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java&q=DownloadManager&ct=rc&cd=1&exact_package=android&sq=)

Answer (score 1):

are you calling flush and close on your outputstream? Like this:

```
while ((count = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0 && running) {
    downloaded += count;
    progressDialog.setProgress(downloaded);
    bout.write(data, 0, count);
}
bout.flush();
bout.close();
```

If not I would start with that. I downloaded a video with similar code and found that for some devices and some videos not calling flush was corrupting and making it unplayable

Comment: Thanks alot for that, I don't know why I wasn't using flush before.  I've added that in now and I'm still getting the error from my users in the new version.  Can you see anything else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another question that talks about this kind of database corruption [Android - database disk image is malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960015/android-database-disk-image-is-malformed).

If you can't fix the database when its in this state, maybe you can try to download it again if and when this error occurs (assuming that this problem is rare and downloading the database again can fix the problem).

Comment: It seems to be happening every time a sgs2 downloads my database.  I have temporary instructions on downloading the database from the web and placing it in the correct directory listed as a work around for sgs2 users.