# Getting SQLite3.Exception: database disk image is malformed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to fetch data from database, my database contains UTF8 characters and when i'm doing so i get "SQLite3.Exception: database disk image is malformed" in exception.

Below is the code:

```
 public ArrayList<String> getDefinations(String query, int column_index) 
 {
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
MatrixCursor mcursor = null;
 try {
Stmt stmt = getDB2().prepare(query);
if (stmt.step()) {
stmt.get_cursor().moveToFirst();
mcursor = stmt.get_cursor();
try {
mcursor.moveToFirst();
 do {
 words.add(mcursor.getString(column_index));
   } while (mcursor.moveToNext());

 } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
 if (MainActivity.logcat_status) {
 Log.e("Error", e + "");
  }
 }
}

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    if (MainActivity.logcat_status) {
     Log.e("Error", e + "");
       }

     }
```

This is the query which i'm using

```
select pos, definition, sample FROM word INNER JOIN sense ON word.wordid = sense.wordid
 INNER JOIN synset ON sense.synsetid = synset.synsetid LEFT JOIN sample ON
 sample.synsetid = synset.synsetid WHERE lemma = 'life'
```

This is what i get in log

```
 01-29 11:04:19.532: E/Error(2023): SQLite3.Exception: database disk image is malformed
01-29 11:04:19.544: E/dalvikvm(2023): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference      
  0x7f00001d (index 7 in a table of size 7)
 01-29 11:04:19.544: E/dalvikvm(2023): VM aborting
  01-29 11:04:19.544: A/libc(2023): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1),   
  thread 2023 (abdkosh.android)
```

Comment: pls check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed

Comment: this may also helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960015/android-database-disk-image-is-malformed?rq=1 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4866