# Why do I keep getting database disk image is malformed on android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I keep getting database disk image is malformed when I try getting the details from the second table added to my SQL database on android studio.
Here are the code snippet for the tables

```
public static final class CourseInfoEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "course_info";
        public static final String COLUMN_COURSE_ID = "course_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_COURSE_TITLE = "course_title";

        public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_COURSE_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, " + COLUMN_COURSE_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
    }
    
    
public static final class NoteInfoEntry implements BaseColumns {
        //Constant for the table name
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "note_info";
        //Constant for the table columns
        public static final String COLUMN_COURSE_ID = "course_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NOTE_TITLE = "note_title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NOTE_TEXT = "note_text";

        //Constant to create the note info table
        public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        COLUMN_NOTE_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        COLUMN_NOTE_TEXT + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_COURSE_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

    }
```

Here is the code to create the tables from the SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NoteKeeper.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public NoteKeeperOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.CourseInfoEntry.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.NoteInfoEntry.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);

        //Adding data to the tables
        DatabaseDataWorker worker = new DatabaseDataWorker(db);
        worker.insertCourses();
        worker.insertSampleNotes();



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

When I check the data for the first table using select * from course_id in the terminal I get this

```
sqlite> select * from course_info;
1|android_intents|Android Programming with Intents
2|android_async|Android Async Programming and Services
3|java_lang|Java Fundamentals: The Java Language
4|java_core|Java Fundamentals: The Core Platform
```

But when I check the data for the second table I get this

```
sqlite> select * from note_info;
Error: database disk image is malformed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error occurs only when I query the SQLite database using command line from the terminal in Android studio.

The data queries just fine when I use the database inspector in android studio which returns the data in the second table with no errors.

NB: The Database Inspector can only be used with your app running in an emulator that supports Android API 26 and above.